# External Javascript doesn't load when called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi so I'm trying to like a javascript file to my web page, when it was in the HTML file it worked fine, but I won't to neaten it up a little by putting the JS in a different file
HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Digital Canvas Web Designs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/Template.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/news.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/tablogo.ico" > <!-- tab logo generated at http://www.favicongenerator.com/ -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Javascript/newshide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

and Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#show").click(function() {
          $("#hidden").show();
   });

   $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").hide();
   });
 });
</script>
```

And the part of HTML where the JS should work.

```
<span id="show">more>></span>
<p id="hidden" hidden>COOL STORY BRO
<span id="hide">less</span> </p>
```

Comment: Forward slashes on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap all into `document.ready`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").show();
     });

     $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#hidden").hide();
     });
});
</script>
```

Also: you have another bug, change the last script for:

```
<script src="Javascript/newshide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[Docs](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: I tried that but still nothing happens when you click the "more". got any other suggestions, thanks

Comment: Yeah the error coming up is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: Okay it was because it shouldn't have <script> stuff on it

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<script src=".\Javascript\newshide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To this

```
<script src="Javascript/newshide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```